# Is there a framework or methodology for evaluating software engineering models and meta-model?

Tags: methods, model, frameworks, metamodel

In software engineering project and research a lot of model have been made.
Is there a framework or methodology for evaluating software engineering models and meta-model especially in qualitative perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. In fact, there are a lot of evaluation models, such as: [Medvidovic, N., Taylor, R.N. A classification and comparison framework for software architecture description languages, Software Engineering, IEEE Transactions on  (Volume:26 ,  Issue: 1), 2000.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/32.825767) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167642309000367), and [that](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=6498478).